# Jquery Ajax Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A have a page that contain two Forms.

- 1st Form `<form> </form>` without ajax.
- 2nd Form load and save from Ajax

When I click on Submit button on the `<form>` (Without ajax), it keep directing to the ajax page. It shouldnt happen.

Click on the **Save** button, it direct to save.php and then direct to ajax_list_inquiries.php for some odd readon?! I have to click on the back button on the browser to go back to forms page. Yes it does save.

For example:

```
<h2> Form (None Ajax) </h2>
<form action="save.php" method="post">
 <input type="name" type="text" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Save" name="SaveEdit" />
</form>


<h2> Ajax Form </h2>
<textarea id="NoteInquiries"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="AddListInquiries" value="Add" />
<div id="ListInquiries"> </div>
```

in the JS script file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function ListInquiries() {
      $("#ListInquiries").load("ajax_list_inquiries.php", {salesid: $("#EditSalesID").val()} );
 }
ListInquiries();
});
```

Comment: Where's your `<form>` tag for the AJAX form?

Comment: On a side note, you are ending the js code with `?>`?

Comment: Does save.php have a header call that redirects to ajax_list_inquiries.php for some reason?

Comment: Is the form already on save.php or on some other page? If it's some other page, then does it redirect after it shows the save.php or does it directly go to ajax_list_inquiries.php?

Comment: StriplingWarrior: I dont need Ajax for <form> tag.

Comment: David, JohnP: It on other page but when it direct to save.php then it should go to header("Location: " . $session->referrer); but it went to ajax_list_inquiries.php for add reason

Comment: Can you include your relevant PHP pages as well?

Comment: I just found out... when I did: exit($session->referrer); it output ajax_list_inquiries.php   (Not sure how did that happen because ajax_list_inquiries.php filename is defined in JS file). Is there any debugging tools I could use find out how that happen?

Comment: As I dig deeper, I echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] from the save.php and it output: ajax_list_inquiries.php - I dont understand how did that happen?

Comment: I found the problem. When ListInquiries() is called (ajax)  and then $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is updated when you request via ajax.